# VBA_get cell row and column number before change event

Tags: excel, vba

I have following code.
I need to get Cell value (old Value position), before event start
Maybe is some better way.

May you help me?

my idea is if you change cell in one row in actual sheet, changes will be updated in main sheet (LL-COVER)

Thank you very much

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Selection_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        oldValue = Target.Value
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        newValue = Target.Value
            If oldValue <> newValue Then
            Dim o As Integer
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim g As Integer
    Dim h As Integer
    
    Set sh1 = ActiveSheet
    Set sh2 = Sheets("LL-COVER")
    
    On Error GoTo ProcError
            
    
        o = oldValue.Row
        c = oldValue.Column
        sh1.Cells(o, c).Select
        Selection.Copy
        b = sh1.Cells(o, 1).Value
        
    
    Sheets("LL-Cover").Select
    On Error GoTo ProcError
            Set fn = Range("A6:A150").Find(what:=b, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not fn Is Nothing Then
                    g = fn.Row
                    h = c
                    sh2.Cells(g, h).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    
                End If
            Range("A6:Q100").Sort Key1:=Range("D6"), Order1:=xlDescending
    ProcError:
      Exit Sub
    
            oldValue = newValue
            
        End If
        
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H5:H150")) Is Nothing Then
            Call Module1.Copy_UNI
            Call Module2.control
        End If
        Sheets("LL-EE").Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the columns in your "actual sheet" (where you make the change) & the columns in the "LL-Cover" sheet (where the change needs to be replicated automatically) are the same. The following code needs to reside in the "actual sheet":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim fn As Range

Dim c As Integer
Dim g As Integer

Set sh1 = ActiveSheet
Set sh2 = Sheets("LL-COVER")

c = Target.Column
b = sh1.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value

With Sheets("LL-Cover").Range("A6:A150")
    Set fn = .Find(b, LookIn:=xlValues)
    g = fn.Row
    sh2.Cells(g, c).Value = Target.Value
End With
End Sub
```